# File name with full path & number of rows in the file

Tags: powershell

I'm able to get the file name, number of rows in the file and file size, but unable to get the file's full path.

```
$measure = Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\Daily_files_YYYY-MM-DD.txt | Measure-Object 
$lines = $measure.Count
echo "line count is: ${lines}"


Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Documents\ -Recurse| 
    ? {! $_.PSIsContainer} |
    Select-Object  Name, @{Name='Size'; Expression={([string]([int]($_.Length / 1KB))) + " KB"}}
```

How can i get in the below format?

File Name : Daily_files_2019-01-10.txt
Path : C:\Users\Documents\
Line count is: 27723
File Size : 23 KB or MB or GB

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Content` and expand the `ReadCount` property to get the number of lines. The full path to the directory of a file is stored in its `DirectoryPath` property.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Documents' -Recurse |
    Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
    Select-Object @{n='File Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Path';e={$_.DirectoryPath}},
        @{Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Expand ReadCount -Last 1}},
        @{n='File Size';e={$_.Length}}
```

I would not recommend doing calculations with the file size or converting it to a string unless the value is meant solely for (human-readable) output.

Note that PowerShell v3 introduced a new parameter `-Directory` for `Get-ChildItem`, so you don't need the extra `Where-Object` pipeline step when using a recent enough version.